# Handling Interrupt in my Android application

Tags: android, exception

Hi I am developing an application that play video in android player.
But i am stuck in between. I used videoView to play video on that.
But inbetween if any incomming call, incomming message come that after
by video can not be resume.
Even if battery low message come than also i can't resume my video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly happens when you return to the screen from the interrupt? You could save the "state" of the playback in internal storage and resume to the point at which it was before. Try utilizing the onResume and onStop methods of your activity.

Check the first image here for more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: i implemented that onstop() and onResume() function.
what i do in that onstop i pause my video just by calling video.pause(); and on resume i resume my video video.resume(); but still its not working.

Comment: By "not working" you mean it loads the video but on a different playback time?  Because videoView also has getCurrentPosition() and seekTo(int time) methods which you can use to first save the current time of your playback and then load to it again.

Comment: No i mean to say after the call is finished no video is played only blank screen is shown.

Comment: It would really help if you posted some code in your initial post. I also guess it would load again the video properly if you created the videoView and started the playback only in the onResume method. That way every time your Activity resumes it will recreate and reinitialize the video playback and it should work for sure.

Comment: now i fixed that issue. Actually i was doing video.resume(). Instead of i have to save the video that is playing and on resume it i will setpath to that video and start it again. But it do not allow me to play video exact where it was stop means suppose video is of 4 mins and when interrupt is generated it was already played of 2 mins and onresume it start play that video from 2 mins onwards

Comment: use getCurrentPosition() and seekTo(int time) to get the time of the video and resume to that moment afterwards.